# Использование операторов цикла | Python

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста способы решения этой задачи, потому-что я уже окончательно запутался. Заранее спасибо!

[image: Задание:]

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно** вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в ответе, готовое решение на блюдечке?

Comment: 1. Рекурсивный метод 2.Циклы

Comment: Да не нужна тут рекурсия. Берём единицу и множим её в цикле по i от нуля до n на (a-i*n).

Comment: Текст следует в виде текста помещать в вопроса, а не картинки (чтобы помочь другим людям с тем же вопросом его найти). Отредактируйте вопрос и явно укажите в чём у вас сложность с "операторами циклов": приведите ваш код, опишите словами что вы хотели получить, что вместо этого происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Каждый раз мы умножаем `P` на нечто, меньшее величины с предыдущей итерации на `n`. Начинаем с `a`, повторяем `n + 1` раз. Итого:

```
n = int(input("n = "))
a = float(input("a = "))

P, multiplier = 1, a
for i in range(n + 1):
    P *= multiplier
    multiplier -= n

print(P)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import mul
try:
    from functools import reduce
except:
    pass

def p(a,n):
    return reduce(mul, [a - i * n for i in range(0, n + 1)])


a = int(input('Введите a: '))
n = int(input('Введите n: '))

print("Вычисленное значение P: {}".format(p(a,n)))
```

Как-то так. Блок try в начале из-за того что неизвестно какая версия Python.

Comment: [a - i * n for i in range(0, n + 1)] следует превратить в итератор: (a - i * n for i in range(0, n + 1)), потому что при росте n список будет линейно потреблять оперативную память, а это десятки мегабайт уже при n >= 1000000
и при неудаче импорта из functools (значит это python 2.x) следует импортировать reduce для python 2.x, pass здесь не вариант

Comment: В python2 `reduce` встроенная функция (build-in). Зачем его импортировать?. Разве при неудачной попытке импорта `functools` она будет перекрыта?

Comment: @MaxU Прошу прощения. Забыл указать что вопрос адресовывался whintu. Он сказал что для python 2.x, `pass` не сработает и `reduce` тоже  нужно импортировать.

Comment: 1- не используйте `except:` (без указания имени)особенно в коде для новичков —это дурная практика, которая может баги скрывать и которой часто по неопытности злоупотребляют. В данном случае можно убрать try/except (импорт работает как на Питоне 2 так и 3). Иначе следовало бы использовать `except ImportError: reduce = reduce` вместо `except: pass` 2- в условии `a` является действительным числом. Замените `a = int(...` на  `a = float(...`

Answer (score 0):

Решение с использованием генераторов:

```
def generator(n):
    r = 0
    for i in range(n + 1):
        yield r
        r += n

n = int(input('Введите n: '))
a = float(input('Введите a: '))

p = 1
for g in generator(n):
    p *= a - g

print('Результат: %f.' % p)
```